# For + count no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Estou tentando fazer com que meu `for` gire de acordo com quantas imagens forem 'inputadas' no SELECT. O problema é que independente de quantas imagens são 'inputadas', ele só salva a primeira. O que tem de errado nessa lógica?

```
private function criarfoto($galeria_id, $file) {
    $extension = "";
    $valores = count($file['Foto']); // SALVA em quantidade,os indices que tem dentro do array.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $valores; $i++) { // faz o loop de acordo com a quantidade de indices no array
        $extension = pathinfo($file['Foto'][$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $allowExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        //print_r($file); 
        if (!in_array($extension, $allowExt)) {
            return false;
        }
        $fotos_galeria = array(
            'galeria_id' => $galeria_id,
            'titulo' => $file['titulo'],
            'descricao' => $file['descricao'],
            'extension' => $extension,
        );
        $this->Foto->create();
        if ($this->Foto->save(array('Foto' => $fotos_galeria))) {
            //die(print_r($fotos_galeria));
            $foto_id = $this->Foto->id;
            if (move_uploaded_file($file['Foto'][$i]['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'galeria' . DS . "{$foto_id}_o.{$extension}")) {
                return $foto_id;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podes editar a pergunta com o resultado de `var_dump($file)` dentro da função `criarfoto()` ? (para saber o que estás a fazer input)

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar **return false** para quando der erro, utilize **continue**, pois o return false, irá fazer com que o loop seja interrompido quando não atender aos critérios, e o continue irá fazer com que o loop siga para o próximo item do array.

Caso você queira identificar também os elementos que tiveram erro no envio, sugiro você alterar o seu tipo de retorno de booleano para array.

Caso você precise obrigatoriamente retornar os Ids das imagens inseridas, você terá de trabalhar com um array bi-dimensional, armazenando o status e a mensagem de retorno em cada caso.

```
<?php
private function criarfoto($galeria_id, $file) {
    $extension = "";
    $valores = count($file['Foto']); // SALVA em quantidade,os indices que tem dentro do array.
    $error = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $valores; $i++) { // faz o loop de acordo com a quantidade de indices no array
        $extension = pathinfo($file['Foto'][$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $allowExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        //print_r($file); 
        if (!in_array($extension, $allowExt)) {
            $error[] = "Extensão inválida para a imagem {$file['Foto'][$i]['name']}";
            continue;
        }
        $fotos_galeria = array(
            'galeria_id' => $galeria_id,
            'titulo' => $file['titulo'],
            'descricao' => $file['descricao'],
            'extension' => $extension,
        );
        $this->Foto->create();
        if ($this->Foto->save(array('Foto' => $fotos_galeria))) {
            //die(print_r($fotos_galeria));
            $foto_id = $this->Foto->id;
            if (!move_uploaded_file($file['Foto'][$i]['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'galeria' . DS . "{$foto_id}_o.{$extension}")) {
                $error[] = "Falha carregando imagem {$file['Foto'][$i]['name']} para o servidor";
            }
        } else {
             $error[] = "Falha salvando a imagem {$file['Foto'][$i]['name']} no banco de dados";
        }
    }
    return (empty($error)) ? true : $error;
}
?>
```